# What's the best strategy for a list of online sound?

Tags: android, listview, caching, audio

I'm going to create an app that list online sounds in a `ListView`and user can listen and download them.

But i'm thinking to this part. When user click to play sound, sound buffered and play. But when user click same item again, sound buffered again!!

I. Can i cache played sound?!

II. Is it? (using of cache)

III. Can I use of this cache when user click download?! Instead of downloading I use of this cache file?!

ps: file sizes are not so big, these are almost between 500KB to 1MB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cache it. There are several libraries available for that, including [this one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache), if you want to cache the files.

Also you can cache http response, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html).